# Can not open navigation drawer on action bar item click

Tags: android, menu, navigation-drawer

i want the right drawer to be opened on menu click
i have used the following code but its not working for some reason

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(),mDrawerLayout,toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (item != null && item.getItemId() == R.id.more) {
                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.END)) {
                    saveToPreferences(getActivity(),KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER,mUserLearnedDrawer+"");
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.END);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

please help me out

> **SOLVED IT BY MODIFYING THE MAINACTIVITY**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case R.id.more:
            if (notificationDrawerFragment.mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.END)){
                notificationDrawerFragment.mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
            }
            else
            { notificationDrawerFragment.mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.END);
            }

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: no i am not getting any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the following by modifying the menu option within the main activity

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case R.id.more:
            notificationDrawerFragment.mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.END);

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this override:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
      mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

also you should have overrides under `ActionBarDrawerToggle`:

```
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) and
public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView)
```

Comment: onPost is never used and i don't have it but where do i put it? within actionbartoggle??

Comment: `onPostCreate(...)` in your `Activity/Fragment`, not within `ActionBarDrawerToggle`

Comment: it's showing can not resolve method onPostCreate(android.os.bundle)

Comment: Are you using `Activity/ActionBarActivity`? are you also getting this error in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`?

Comment: So there is no method `onPostCreate(...) ` in `Fragment`. I think you should go to docment about `Navigation Drawer`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I had learnt this from SO:

```
@Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.more) {
                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
saveToPreferences(getActivity(),KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER,mUserLearnedDrawer+" ");
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Right" and "END" are the same thing