# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file error

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have created an app where when it opens it shows map and when I want to open a `NavigationFragment` when I press a button in ActionBar. I implemented map in my app and it worked just fine but when I added `NavigationDrawer` I got this error:

```
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408): Process: com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample, PID: 5408
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample/com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #72: Error inflating class fragment
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #72: Error inflating class fragment
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:83)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     ... 10 more
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:604)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2108)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5286)
04-18 13:20:49.942: E/AndroidRuntime(5408):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
```

**XML file**

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <com.wunderlist.slidinglayer.SlidingLayer
                android:id="@+id/slidingLayer1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/layer_size"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

            >

            <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#14ad8f"
               >

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/buttonClose"
                        style="@style/ButtonRed"
                        android:onClick="buttonClicked"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="@string/close_button_container"/>


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Nosaukums"
                    android:id="@+id/fragNosaukums" />
            </RelativeLayout>



        </com.wunderlist.slidinglayer.SlidingLayer>

        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"

            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    //VARIABLES DEFINED HERE


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fragNosaukums = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fragNosaukums);

        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.getUiSettings();
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        bindViews();
        initState();

        mSlidingLayer.bringToFront();


    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        }
    }

    /**
     * View binding
     */
    private void bindViews() {
        mSlidingLayer = (SlidingLayer) findViewById(R.id.slidingLayer1);
//        swipeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.swipeText);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the origin state of the layer
     */
    private void initState() {

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        setupSlidingLayerPosition(prefs.getString("layer_location", "right"));

        setupShadow(prefs.getBoolean("layer_has_shadow", false));
        setupLayerOffset(prefs.getBoolean("layer_has_offset", false));
        setupPreviewMode(prefs.getBoolean("preview_mode_enabled", false));
    }

    private void setupSlidingLayerPosition(String layerPosition) {

        LayoutParams rlp = (LayoutParams) mSlidingLayer.getLayoutParams();
        int textResource;
        Drawable d;

//        if (layerPosition.equals("right")) {
            textResource = R.string.swipe_right_label;
            d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.container_rocket_right);

            mSlidingLayer.setStickTo(SlidingLayer.STICK_TO_RIGHT);


        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
//        swipeText.setCompoundDrawables(null, d, null, null);
//        swipeText.setText(getResources().getString(textResource));
        mSlidingLayer.setLayoutParams(rlp);
    }

    private void setupShadow(boolean enabled) {
        if (enabled) {
            mSlidingLayer.setShadowSizeRes(R.dimen.shadow_size);
            mSlidingLayer.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.sidebar_shadow);
        } else {
            mSlidingLayer.setShadowSize(0);
            mSlidingLayer.setShadowDrawable(null);
        }
    }

    private void setupLayerOffset(boolean enabled) {
        int offsetDistance = enabled ? getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.offset_distance) : 0;
        mSlidingLayer.setOffsetDistance(offsetDistance);
    }

    private void setupPreviewMode(boolean enabled) {
        int previewOffset = enabled ? getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.preview_offset_distance) : -1;
        mSlidingLayer.setPreviewOffsetDistance(previewOffset);
    }

    public void buttonClicked(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
//        case R.id.buttonOpen:
//            mSlidingLayer.openLayer(true);
//            break;
        case R.id.buttonClose:
            mSlidingLayer.closeLayer(true);
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if (mSlidingLayer.isOpened()) {
                mSlidingLayer.closeLayer(true);
                return true;
            }

        default:
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {


            case R.id.addNewEvent:

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddEvent.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                ;

            case android.R.id.home:
                //Do stuff
                //mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                return true;
        }


        return true;
    }


}
```

Can anyone help ?

**UPDATE**

I added this line: 
`android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` 
as `kamil zych` suggested and i got this error now:

```
04-18 13:45:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(5473): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample.NavigationDrawerFragment that is not a Fragment
04-18 13:45:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(5473):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:606)
04-18 13:45:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(5473):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
04-18 13:45:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(5473):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2108)
04-18 13:45:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(5473):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5286)
04-18 13:45:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(5473):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
04-18 13:45:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(5473): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
```

and this is `fragment_navigation_drawer`:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent" android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#cccc" tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

fragment_main:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update**

NavigationDrawerFragment:

```
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * Remember the position of the selected item.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    /**
     * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
     * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
     */
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    /**
     * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
     */
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
        // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.title_section1),
                        getString(R.string.title_section2),
                        getString(R.string.title_section3),
                }));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     */
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
        // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
     * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
     */
    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see @layout/fragment_navigation_drawer

Comment: the error is mentioned clearly in the logcat `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #72: Error inflating class fragment`

Comment: @Virus and i am asking how can i fix that?

Comment: read the error carefully they provide the answer it's as simple as that

Comment: @Virus i haven't faced this problem ever

Comment: in your second logcat it's directly mentioned that the `NavigationDrawerfragment` is not a fragment so extend it to fragment

Comment: it is extended to Fragment i will update my question with NavigationDrawerFragment

Comment: i see you are trying to use menu to open and close drawer, if you are trying to implement to open the navigationdrawer on menu click check this post of mine  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350891/can-not-open-navigation-drawer-on-action-bar-item-click

Comment: post your navigationdrawerfragment class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here i had to add this line in my java code:

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
// Set the list's click listener
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to end your xml with a closing that matches the opening tag.

So if your xml begins with

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  ..
  .. >
```

You have to close it with that as well, so add this at the bottom of the file

```
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: i pasted the code incorrectly i just updated my code with correct version. Sorry for confusing you

Comment: @Girts Which code? The xml looks the same and still missing the closing tag

Comment: @Girts my android studio complains that you can't use relativelayout and button tags inside the slidinglayer tags, perhaps remove them?

Comment: Show us the @layout/fragment_navigation_drawer then please. The error is in an xml file somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I think that your navigation drawer fragment should have android:name specified in the same way that your map fragment has.

```
  <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    <!-- android:name attribute should be here -->
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First, did you declare `MainActivity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, because the logcat said:`Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample/com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample.MainActivity}:`.
2. Second, did you add the library including `SlidingLayer` into your project, because the logcat said:`at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
   com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:83)`. Maybe you need to check your `SlidingLayer`.
3. Third, did you add `</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>` at the bottom of your layout? It seems you didn't close your `DrawerLayout` as the `xml` you posted.
4. Forth, why did you call `googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();` after `setContentView`? I don't think the `Fragment` has already been loaded when you try to `getMap()`.

Comment: MainActivity declared in Manifest - check

Comment: Library added and xml file corrected still the same error

Comment: You have to ensure your `fragment` is loaded completely when you want to get the `map`, do you?

Comment: I mean you cant call `googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap()` immediately after `setContentView`.

Comment: Why can't I? it worked perfectly with map when i didnt add NavigationDrawer